# Metamask won't display balance on Ropsten test network

Tags: metamask, ropsten, mastering-ethereum

Going over first chapters Mastering Ethereum book, I've obtained some ether from a faucet on Ropsten Test network, but Metamask (after 2 days and 18K confirmations) still shows the balance of 0 ETH, while nevertheless correctly showing the funding transaction. Tried browser restart, switch to other network and back, balance still zero.

What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't really matter the balance you see on MetaMask, it's just a user interface. If you can see the balance on [Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/), you can proceed with whatever you wanted to do, albeit you may need to import your mnemonic in another wallet.